# Application.match not working with merged cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have my code which finds a certain column and go to its last row value and display it. My problem is that the application.match is not working on the merged cells. Here's my code;

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

With ActiveSheet

    Set rng = Sheets("COMPAS").Range("A10:" & .Range("ZZ9").End(xlToRight).Address)
    col = Application.Match("*Crt.*", rng, 0)

    If IsError(col) Then

        Sheets("MACRO TEMPLATE").Cells(2, 2) = 0

    Else

        col = Application.Match("*Crt. Accrual*", rng, 0)
        LastRow = Sheets("COMPAS").Cells(1000000, col).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("MACRO TEMPLATE").Cells(2, 2) = Sheets("COMPAS").Cells(LastRow, col)

    End If

End With
```

What I'm trying to find is the "Crt. Accrual". Unlike "Allotment - Total" which is on row 9 and 10(merged) "Crt. Accrual" is on row 10. not merged with row 9.

Any response would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you use builtin function within VBA you need to use the right object. `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(...)`

Comment: It gives me a runtime error 438 that's why I've used application.match without worksheetfunction.

Comment: I think your **Crt. Accrual** has a manual line feed in it (Alt-Enter)? If so, the match will NOT find it unless you include it (`CHAR(10)`). Try remove the line feed or match with a different string.

Comment: What is manual line feed? By the way, when I run my code per line, col gives error 2042.

Comment: Have you tried `"*Crt.*Accrual*"`? Since you have the bracket in the cell but not in the Match string. Which line gives error 2042?

Comment: @JohnF is this merged cell static? e.g. it will always remain in this range

Comment: @JohnF Next time please include row and column headers in screenshot if you are dealing with rows and/or columns. We can only guess the "Crt. (Accrual" is similar to your highlighted cell.

Comment: @PatricK I'm sorry about that. "Crt. (Accrual)" is at range AG10. But the range is not static. Also "Allotment - Total" is in merged row(9 and 10), "leave pay" is in merged column(AF:AH, row 9)

Comment: @bonCodigo The cell is not static. Its range changes

Comment: Check if your code can run without bugs/failing in an non-merged range.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've fix my own issue by placing the range on the match. 
    col = Application.Match("*Crt*", Sheets("COMPAS").Range("A10:ZZ10"), 0)

Answer (score 1):

A few issues with your code:

1. This syntax doesn't give you what you'd expect

   `Set rng = Sheets("COMPAS").Range("A10:" & .Range("ZZ9").End(xlToRight).Address)`

   You could use something like this

   `Set rng = Sheets("COMPAS").Range("A9:ZZ10")`
2. Match can search one array (one row or column), so you'll have to use Match for each row

   - To search on multiple rows you could use Find
3. "col" needs to be declared as a variant (not sure how you have it declared)
4. You need to check for errors every time you perform the Match (in the Else block as well)

Notes:

- If you merge cell A1 with A2, and place "Test" in the merged cells, the "Test value will be found in row 1 (A1), and A2 will be empty

This (untested) code shows how you can use Match on multiple rows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SubName()
    Const HDR1 As String = "*Crt.*"
    Const HDR2 As String = "*Crt. Accrual*"

    Dim row1 As Range, row2 As Range
    Dim col1 As Variant, col2 As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long, macroCell As Range

    With Worksheets("COMPAS").UsedRange
        Set row1 = .Rows(9)
        Set row2 = .Rows(10)
    End With
    With Application
        col1 = .Match(HDR1, row1, 0)
        col2 = .Match(HDR2, row1, 0)
        If IsError(col1) Then col1 = .Match(HDR1, row2, 0)
        If IsError(col2) Then col2 = .Match(HDR2, row2, 0)
    End With

    Set macroCell = Worksheets("MACRO TEMPLATE").Cells(2, 2)

    If IsError(col1) Or IsError(col2) Then
        macroCell.Value2 = 0
    Else
        With Worksheets("COMPAS")
            lastRow = .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, col2).End(xlUp).Row
            macroCell.Value2 = .Cells(lastRow, col2).Value2
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't give me errors but it doesn't give the correct value. It gives zero. When I run the code per line, col is equals to error 2042

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've fix my own issue by placing the range on the match. 
    col = Application.Match("*Crt*", Sheets("COMPAS").Range("A10:ZZ10"), 0)